# Class Specific constants should they be wrapped in a nested class?

Tags: c#, constants, nested-class

If I have constants in a class that are related to each other lets say strings used to write/read Xml file for MyClass, should I wrap them in a nested class Xml inside MyClass? Or just define them without wrapping in MyClass? If it is a good idea to wrap them than what if only part of those constants should be accessible to the outside world for example only the Xml.Name and the rest are Xml attributes that MyClass will use for recreating objects, what would I set the protection level of my nested class to?

Comment: I don't have an opinion on whether you should use a nested class or not, but if you do then I should think that the nested class would be public, with externally-visible members as public and internally-visible members as internal.

Comment: Be aware that publicly accessible constants can result in some weird scenarios. Assemblies using your assembly are free to embed the constants in their own binary. The result is even if you change the value it might not be reflected in the assemblies using your code (and that is using the newly build version of your code). Therefor static readonly is often a good idea when you wish to make your constants public (internal does not cause this issue of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a `nested-class` as an object that only makes sense within the context of another object; and whose logic requires properties of this other object. Given that, I've never designed a `nested-class` that I didn't later refactor away. And I see the perceived need for a `public nested-class` as a red-flag for a troubled design.

Regardless, your question has me considering whether they are potentially useful. So even though I won't be using this sort of design it may work for you.

I did want to mention that `const` should only be used for things that never change. Like the hours in a day or the speed of light. I can't exactly tell from your question but something like `Xml.Name` appears to be variable. I suggest using `readonly` for these properties. Possibly, `static readonly` if they're consistent through all instances. This will steer you clear of the [many pitfalls of `const`](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/c3/constant-comprehension).

The following is a `class` I mocked up to demonstrate what I'd recommend for your design:

```
public class MyClass
{   
    public string Title { get; set; }

    Xml _xml;
    public Xml MyXml
    {
        get { return _xml; }
        set { _xml = value; }
    }    

    public MyClass(string xmlName, object xmlAttributes)
    {
        _xml = new Xml(xmlName, xmlAttributes);        
    }

        public class Xml
        {
            private readonly string _name;
            public string Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
            }

            private readonly object _attributes;
            internal object Attributes
            {
                get { return _attributes; }
            }

            public Xml(string name, object attributes)
            {
                _name = name;
                _attributes = attributes;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to move the constants to a nested class.

**Accessibility:**
Make constants only needed by *MyClass* *private*.
Make constants only needed by classes which are in same assembly as *MyClass* *internal*.
Make constants only needed by subclasses of *MyClass* and by *MyClass* itself *protected*.
Make constants only needed by classes which are in same assembly as *MyClass* or by subclasses of *MyClass* and by *MyClass* itself *internal protected*.
Make constants also needed by classes in other assemblies than *MyClass*'s one *public*.

**Naming:**
If you have many constants in one class use good prefixes to categories them. So the reader can find faster the right one.

Comment: Generally don't make constants public. Constants across assembly boundaries can be "fun" (see comment to the question)

Comment: @RuneFS And *protected* and *internal protected* also need to be *static readonly* because sub classes can be in other assemblies.

Comment: Yeah the point is as you say everything that is accessible from another assembly should be static readonly rather than const